# How to update the url link when clicking the tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, web, elementor

Hi i have three tabs in my website for the post these are created based on the elementor plugin in wordpress i want to provide the url when navigating to the tabs for that i have written the some script it is working but there is an issue when i clicking on the onetab it is navigating to the different tab can you help me on fixing this one

```html
<script>
window.onload = function () {
  
  
   let search = ""
  
 var dmi = document.getElementById("elementor-tab-title-3201");
  if(window.location.search!=="?DataMonetizationIndex"){
      search = "";
   dmi.onclick = changeLink;
    search="?DataMonetizationIndex";
 
  }

  var dp = document.getElementById("elementor-tab-title-3203");
  if(window.location.search!=="?DataProducts"){
      search = "";
   dp.onclick = changeLink;
   search="?DataProducts";
        
  }
  
  var ans = document.getElementById("elementor-tab-title-3202");
  if(window.location.search!=="?Analysis"){
      search = "";
   ans.onclick = changeLink;
   search="?Analysis";
        
  }
  
  
   function changeLink() {
     
     window.location.search=search;
        
        }
        
}



document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
setTimeout(function() {

jQuery(function($){

let desktoptitles = $('.elementor-tab-desktop-title');
let mobiletitles = $('.elementor-tab-mobile-title');

let strings = ['?DataMonetizationIndex',
'?Analysis','?DataProducts'
];

strings.forEach( (string,i) => {
if (window.location.href.indexOf(string) > -1) {
desktoptitles.eq(i).click();
mobiletitles.eq(i).click();
$('html, body').animate({
scrollTop: desktoptitles.eq(i).offset().top - 100
},'slow');
} } );
}); }, 1200); });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is not clear what is your problem, but looking at code i think that a problem could be in the firs part, on `window.onload = function () {...}`
You check for window.location.search and you assign the variable search. The problem is that you have 2 possible value to assign in a single variable.

Let me explain my doubt with an example:

Assuming that you are in the ?DataMonetizationIndex tab.
On the load you first assing

```
search="?DataProducts";
```

and then

```
search="?Analysis"
```

Now, when a tab is clicked, and the `changeLink()` fired, the value of global variable **search**  it's always the second assignement, no matter wich tab are you clicking. (in this example it's always ?Analysis)

This could be a problem.

Why don't you simply assing changeLink() to all tab/button and inside the function check wich one was clicked and update the window.location.search ?
You can perfom it using a custom data-attribute , or simply checking the ID of the clicked element.
What I would do in this code is probably a function like this

```
function changeLink2(){
        var idClicked = $(this).id

        switch (idClicked){
            case "elementor-tab-title-3201":
                 window.location.search = "?DataMonetizationIndex"
                break;
            case "elementor-tab-title-3203":
                 window.location.search = "?DataProducts"
                break;
            case "elementor-tab-title-3202":
                 window.location.search = "?Analysis"
                break;
        }

    }
```

This will work with an arbitrary number of tab and it is easy to implement future changes.

UPDATE

Applied to your code it could be something like this

```
<script >
    window.onload = function() {


        //let search = ""

        var dmi = document.getElementById("elementor-tab-title-3201");
        /*if (window.location.search !== "?DataMonetizationIndex") {
            search = "";
            dmi.onclick = changeLink;
            search = "?DataMonetizationIndex";
        }*/
        dmi.onclick = changeLink;

        var dp = document.getElementById("elementor-tab-title-3203");
        /*if (window.location.search !== "?DataProducts") {
            search = "";
            dp.onclick = changeLink;
            search = "?DataProducts";

        }*/
        dp.onclick = changeLink;

        var ans = document.getElementById("elementor-tab-title-3202");
        /*if (window.location.search !== "?Analysis") {
            search = "";
            ans.onclick = changeLink;
            search = "?Analysis";

        }*/
        ans.onclick = changeLink

        function changeLink() {

            //window.location.search = search;

            var idClicked = $(this).id

            switch (idClicked){
                case "elementor-tab-title-3201":
                     window.location.search = "?DataMonetizationIndex"
                    break;
                case "elementor-tab-title-3203":
                     window.location.search = "?DataProducts"
                    break;
                case "elementor-tab-title-3202":
                     window.location.search = "?Analysis"
                    break;
            }
        }


    }



document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {

        jQuery(function($) {

            let desktoptitles = $('.elementor-tab-desktop-title');
            let mobiletitles = $('.elementor-tab-mobile-title');

            let strings = ['?DataMonetizationIndex',
                '?Analysis', '?DataProducts'
            ];

            strings.forEach((string, i) => {
                if (window.location.href.indexOf(string) > -1) {
                    desktoptitles.eq(i).click();
                    mobiletitles.eq(i).click();
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: desktoptitles.eq(i).offset().top - 100
                    }, 'slow');
                }
            });
        });
    }, 1200);
}); <
</script>
```

The second part of your script (that one that look on load what tab is active and scroll to that item triggering the click) seems ok

Please accept answer if it solve your problem :)

Comment: Hi what your understanding is correct that is the problem iam facing,you given a code for applying the all tabs/button that iam not able to apply for the all the tabs because these are not an individual tabs there is a tabs component in the elementor iam using that these all tabs comes under the one section i can place an html code near to the entire tabs section in that i have written the code

Comment: HI #Andrea_86 can you please update the above code that i posted i want to navigate the proper tab what i clicked on it

Comment: Added an update to the answer, just because today i'm good :)